# C# application using database from wrong location

Tags: c#, winforms

I have setup my sqlite database path as

```
  string AppPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
  dbName = AppPath + "\\data\\rbssystems.sqlite";
```

But when application is packed and installed using setup, my application uses

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files\RBS\data
```

it should be using

```
C:\Program Files\RBS\data
```

Can anyone tell whats going around and how to make it read database from

```
C:\Program Files\RBS\data
```

Thanks

Comment: well....where are you executing the application from?

Comment: C:\Program Files\RBS\

Comment: ! wonder why the post is downvoted, for me it seem to be a genuine question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app can't write to `C:\Program Files` unless it has administrative privileges. Windows automatically redirects you to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files` instead. See this article for the explanation: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx

Application data should always be in the AppData folder, never in Program Files.

Comment: well in `app.manifest` file i have set `<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" UIAccess="true" />`, it should allow to write, shouldn't it

Comment: @WatsMyName, it would work with `level="requireAdministrator"` (and you would get the UAC prompt when you start the app)